# payment module in prestashop 1.6.1.x doesn't send total price with shipment

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, payment-processing, prestashop-modules

In my Prestashop store, I have a payment module that sends the total amount to an external API:

```
    /** CART ITEMS */
    $products = $cart->getProducts();
    $CartItems = [];
    $api_currency_id = (int)Currency::getIdByIsoCode($currency_iso);
    foreach($products as $product) {
        if ($this->context->currency->id != $api_currency_id) {
            $price = Tools::convertPrice((float)$product['price_wt'], $this->context->currency, false);
            $price = Tools::convertPrice((float)$price, $api_currency_id);
        } else {
            $price = (float)$product['price_wt'];
        }
        $CartItem['Amount'] = Tools::ps_round($price) ;
        $CartItem['Currency'] = $currency_iso;
        $CartItem['Name'] = $product['name'];
        $CartItem['Description'] = strip_tags($product['description_short']);
        $CartItem['Quantity'] = (int)$product['cart_quantity'];
        $CartItem['IsTaxFree'] = $product['price'] != $product['price_wt'];
```

The problem is when the purchase includes the shipping price, the amount that sends to the API is without the shipping .

what do I need to fix in the code, so that the $CartItem['Amount'] will include the shipping cost?

Answer (score 0):

The shipping price is a different amount. With a proper flag, you can get all the prices you need using `Cart::getOrderTotal()`. For instance:

`$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::ONLY_SHIPPING)`

It will return you the amount of shipping for a given shopping cart.